# How to make two read operations atomic in Redis, when second read key is depends on first read value?

Tags: node.js, redis

I have two Redis operation, **get** and **hgetall**

```
client.get("player_1", function(table_key) {
            if (table_key) {
                client.hgetall(table_key, function(table_data) {
                    if (table_data) {
                        /*Some operation*/
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

In above example, **hgetall** can run after table_key value from **get** query, is there any way to combine both these in one atomic query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `EVAL` to do it. To return multiple values use `{}` in the return statement.